# Last Element from List of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

Here is a simple piece of code that is giving me the wrong output but I can't figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    list<int*> l;
    int x = 7;
    int* y = &x;
              //it works if I put    list<int*> l;   on this line instead.
    l.push_back(y);
    cout << **l.end() << endl;   // not 7
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `void main` is non-standard and `l.end()` doesn't "point" to anywhere in particular in a dereferencing sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.end()` returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the list container.The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the list container. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.

use `front` or `back` member functions

```
cout << *l.front() << endl;   
cout << *l.back() << endl;
```

[Check this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)